# Why add document and field update can not work together in solrJ

Tags: solr, solrj

All:

Right now, I want to send a lot of documents to SOLR for indexing with SOLRJ, and then update certain field(s). When the number of documents is small or I manually run these two jobs, the update works. But when I run these two jobs in one piece of code with a lot of documents, the update part doesn't work.

```
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/");
// Suppose here are lots of documents using a for/while loop to add them( or multithread)
{
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", ids[i]);
doc.addField("content", content[i]);
solr.add(doc);
}

solr.commit();

// Similar for/while loop here
{
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("id", id[i]);
    Map<String, List<String>> oper = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    oper.put("set", updatecontent[i]);
// I know I did not update the same content field, but added another. But they should be similar and it works in the case of only a few documents
    doc.addField("updatecontent", oper);
    solr.add(doc);
}
solr.commit();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> While the update procedure may be the problem here, as [Atomic Updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) have a lot of touchy requirements (particularly in which fields must or *must not* be stored), my answer below will only help if avoiding atomic updates would help, which may not be the best option or an option at all.

You haven't said whether there's an error message when this fails to work, but the first thing that jumps out at me is that you say you are attempting to update Solr, but Solr doesn't always support updates. You could create a **complete** Solr document, delete the old document from Solr, then re-add the document. Your second loop would look something like this:

```java
// Similar for/while loop here
{
   SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
   doc.addField("id", id[i]);

   //this is the original content - if you still need it.
   doc.addField("content", content[i]);

   doc.addField("updatecontent", updatecontent[i]);

   solr.deleteById(id[i]); // this will not fail, even if the record isn't in Solr.
   solr.add(doc);
}
solr.commit();
```

If you cannot recover all of the data in the Solr record that should remain unchanged, either from the original data source or by querying Solr, you may have trouble updating the Solr record correctly. (This requirement remains true even if you are sending only the updated fields through [Atomic Updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates), which is a server-side implementation of the same solution. Solr will build an complete, updated document, delete the document, and re-add it.)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not quite understand why you want to delete the ducument, I just want to add one more field or update certain field in that document.

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't actually used Solr's [atomic updates](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) yet, and didn't realize that this was something you could do. It looks like there are quite a few limitations to this feature, so you may need to add some detail about the failure before anyone can help debug. For instance, you might add some information about the kind of error you're getting.